# Is it possible to see how much memory space is reserved for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, memory-management

I am having a problem with VS 2010, to have my silver-light solution build successfully. A friend of mine has no problem to build the same solution and he has much more RAM than I have and he has a 64 bit OS.

I am still not sure if my problem is lack of memory -The build fails by complaining one project is not build so that a relevant .dll is missing-.

So I would be happy to see how much memory is reserved for VS in my local machine.

Do you know if VS is limited to some fixed memory space; if yes, how can I learn its size and where I can increase that?

*One additional note is*: We force VS to generate one big context from the Db we have; we are kind of suspicious if the file is too big to be handled by VS.

thanks

Comment: what is the build error?

Comment: The error is something like: N:\XxxSVN\Web\SilverXxxRIAServicesLibrary\Bin\Debug\SilverXxxRIAServicesLibrary.dll' could not be found SilveXxxx. But I can build that project individually without a problem.

Comment: How can I prove that? 2 colleagues of mine who have same PC config with me deals with the same issue while another colleague with a better PC does not.

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM are you using? I suggest you use a minimum of 3 gb for laptops and 1 gb for desktops; my asp.net project is also huge and struggled when running on 512 mb ram, so I upgraded it to 1 gb and it's quite good.

Comment: I read an article saying that vs 2008 is limited to 2 gb space dont know how much is vs 2010 limited too !!